# Error connecting to SQL Server.PDOException Object (Azure)

Tags: php, azure

i'm trying to connect to my Azure SQL db using PHP that is run by my other server every night at 00:00 via cronjob. When it runs shows this error in logs:

```
 Error connecting to SQL Server.PDOException Object
(
    [message:protected] => could not find driver
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 0
    [file:protected] => /home3/nappuntx/public_html/modifiche/export.php
    [line:protected] => 73
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home3/nappuntx/public_html/modifiche/export.php
                    [line] => 73
                    [function] => __construct
                    [class] => PDO
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => sqlsrv:server = tcp:prgsophie.database.windows.net,1433; Database = test_db
                            [1] => userTest
                            [2] => pswtest
                        )

                )

        )

    [previous:Exception:private] => 
    [errorInfo] => 
)
1
```

As mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-driver-for-sql-server?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15
I Should install PDO Drivers in my Linux Server? I'm not sure because i've read here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php " PDO and the PDO_SQLITE driver is enabled by default as of PHP 5.1.0. You may need to enable the PDO driver for your database of choice; consult the documentation for database-specific PDO drivers to find out more about that. " so theoretically it is already included in my PHP driver. I use PHP Version 7.2.26 on my Linux Red Hat server...
Waiting for support, thank you.

Comment: It says so but you haven't checked. Execute `php -m | grep 'pdo_sqlite'` at the shell's command line, do you get anything back?

Comment: viewing phpinfo(); i can see: 1) --enable-pdo=shared 2) API Extensions mysqli,pdo_mysql ' 3) PDO drivers mysql, sqlite ENABLED. I actually need MySQL driver support for PDO driver and it seems i have, but i don't know why it gives me that exception.

Comment: Then just use `mysqli`, it can do anything PDO can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me repeat your needs first. I see you were trying to use PHP PDO to connect Azure SQL Database, but the error information shows there is not a PHP driver to support SQL Azure connection, and your environment is as below.

1. PHP 7.4, it seems that you installed v7.4 via compile it manually, please ensure you have installed it to `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` or other system path.
2. Linux Server, but I don't know what Linux distribution you used, so I will assume that's Ubuntu/Debian.

Next first, you need to refer to the section [`PHP Version Support`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-drivers-for-sql-server-support-matrix?view=sql-server-ver15#php-version-support) of the offical document `Microsoft PHP Drivers for SQL Server Support Matrix` to know what version of PHP PDO driver for Azure SQL Database is for PHP v7.4, as the figure below.

[image]

There seems to be not any version for PHP 7.4, but the latest version 5.6 is the only choice.

Then, you need to move to [`Download the Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) to click the link [Microsoft Drivers 5.6 for PHP for SQL Server](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases/tag/v5.6.0) for Linux and macOS, it will redirect to its GitHub release page [`Production Release for the PHP drivers Version 5.6.0 for SQL Server`](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases/tag/v5.6.0) and move to the page bottom, as the figure below.

[image]

Ofcourse, you can download the packages as you wish, but I think the simple way is to install `sqlsrv` and `pdo_sqlsrv` via `pecl`, and the first thing is to ready `pecl` via `sudo apt install php-pear` on Ubuntu/Debian Linux, then to do these below.

```
sudo pecl install sqlsrv
sudo pecl install pdo_sqlsrv
```

Now, I think you can try again for your PHP Script, may restart Apache/Nginx first if you used it.

---

Update: For using PHP 7.2 on RHEL, I recommended that please refer to the offical tutorial [`Create PHP apps using SQL Server on RHEL`](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/php/rhel) to know how to do step by step in details.

Comment: Thank you very much @Peter i'll try with your suggestion!

Comment: Realized that my Linux Server is Red Hat, sorry for missing this information, and the PHP version is 7.2.26 so as you said @Peter i'll try to install the 5.6 Driver from Microsoft on my Server which its hosted so, i'll open a ticked. Last Question, what about freeTDS instead? Do you know it? would it be helpful?

Comment: @SimoneDeLuca I updated my post for you, it's simple. Please use the offical solution recommended by MS.

Comment: thank you very much! i'm going to follow the tutorial