# Connect to Azure SQL database with PHP

Tags: php, sql, azure

I try to connect to my azure database only with the provided connection string. However I just get this error message:

Error connecting to SQL Server.PDOException Object ( [message:protected] => could not find driver [string:Exception:private] => [code:protected] => 0 [file:protected] => C:\XAMPP\htdocs\folder\Databaseconnection.php [line:protected] => 4 [trace:Exception:private] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [file] => C:\XAMPP\htdocs\folder\Databaseconnection.php [line] => 4 [function] => __construct [class] => PDO [type] => -> [args] => Array ( [0] => sqlsrv:server = tcp:{server}.database.windows.net,1433; Database = testdb [1] => {username} [2] => {password} ) ) ) [previous:Exception:private] => [errorInfo] => ) 1

The servername username and password is obviously changed here. I also allowed my own IP adress on the server firewall settings. Any help appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is caused by that you want to use PHP PDO to connect Azure SQL Database, but the error information shows there is not a PHP driver to support SQL Azure connection.

You could reference this blog:[Error connecting to SQL Server.PDOException Object (Azure)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59936735/error-connecting-to-sql-server-pdoexception-object-azure).

You need to refer to the section [PHP Version Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-drivers-for-sql-server-support-matrix?view=sql-server-ver15#php-version-support) of the offical document `Microsoft PHP Drivers for SQL Server Support Matrix` to know what version of PHP PDO driver for Azure SQL Database is for PHP v7.4:

[image]

Please choose the suitable PHP version and SQL Server driver.

You could  [Download the Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) for your system. Also reference [Production Release for the PHP drivers Version 5.6.0 for SQL Server](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases/tag/v5.6.0).

Hope this helps.